# how to get selected values from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to get the selected values from the table.

Created a HTMl table:

```html
<tr>
  <th>Start Date</th>
  <th>End Date</th>
  <th>Project</th>
  <th>Charge#Field</th>
  <th>Employee Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="date" id="startdate">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="date" id="enddate">
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="projkey" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="A">a</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="chargefield">
      <option value="charge">charge Number</option>
      <option value="Substatus">Substatus</option>

    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="userkey" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
      <option value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
      <option value="BHU">BHU</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

How to retrieve the selected fields of `startdate`,`end date`,`projectkey` ,`charge`,`user` using jquery.

Comment: This is very basic question. Can you share what you have tried and we can poitn you in right direction. This might helpl: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the values you can use jQuery's `map()`.

```
var array = $("input, select").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

Otherwise create it yourself, maybe with a loop, or `$.each` or something else.

```
var data = {};
$("input, select").each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    data[element.attr("id")] = element.val();
});
```

Or even possible, a direct and static access of the elements.

```
var startdate   = $("#startdate").val();
var enddate     = $("#enddate").val();
var projkey     = $("#projkey").val();
var chargefield = $("#chargefield").val();
var userkey     = $("#userkey").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant get the values from the selects

```
$( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var startdate = $('#startdate').val();
var enddate = $('#enddate').val();
var projkey = $('#projkey').val();
var chargefield = $('#chargefield').val();
var userkey = $('#userkey').val();
```

Comment: First, this is a basic question and you should let OP share effort. Second, if you still wish to answer, you should explain it. Just posting code is not good enough.